# How do I know if I am in fallback mode?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, radeon, fglrx

If Gnome 3 appears to be exacltly like Gnome Classic, does that mean that it is running in Fallback Mode?  If this is the case, then how do I force it to return to Gnome 3?

Comment: Yes, do you have `mutter`installed?

Answer (score 0):

Go to system settings>>details>>Graphics if you are in fallback mode, it will say fallback next to "experience"

Comment: Awesome.  I think we're getting somewhere because it is in fallback mode.  How do I get it back to normal mode? VESA: 2 is what is listed as the driver although I installed Catalyst 12.8.  @Uri, I have not installed mutter myself, so I would say no.